# QAbstractSocket strange behavior when connection is closed from server side

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I am implementing a simple TCP socket class that inherits from QAbstractSocket. I was testing my code, then I noticed that QAbstractSocket was presenting a strange behavior. When the connection is ended from the server side QAbstractSocket never emits disconnected() signal, but it keeps emitting readyRead() signal repeatedly.

I am connecting the SimpleTCPSocket class signals to my Widget slots in the constructor of my Widget class:

```
connect(simpleSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readDataFromSimpleSocket()));
connect(simpleSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onSimpleSocketDisconnect()));
```

Here is the implementation of my slots:

```
void Widget::readDataFromSimpleSocket()
{
    QString aux;
    size_t sizeOfDataAvilable;
    sizeOfDataAvilable = simpleSocket->bytesAvailable();
    aux = "Message received from readDataFromSimpleSocket slot: bytes available ";
    aux += QString::number(sizeOfDataAvilable);
    qDebug() << aux;
    dataFromServer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * sizeOfDataAvilable);
    simpleSocket->read(dataFromServer, sizeOfDataAvilable);
    qDebug() << "All data has been read.";
}

void Widget::onSimpleSocketDisconnect()
{
    qDebug() << "Disconnected!!";
}
```

When the server application is closed, I am getting the readReady() signal, but no bytes are available to be read. Here is my output.

```
"Message received from readDataFromSimpleSocket slot: bytes available 0"
All data has been read.
```

I am getting the above output like "forever". No matter how much time is elapsed after the connection is closed on server side, my SimpleTCPSocket class never emits the disconnected() signal. 
Here is the header file for my socket class:

```
#include "simpletcpsocket_global.h"
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QAuthenticator>
#include <QNetworkProxy>

class SIMPLETCPSOCKETSHARED_EXPORT SimpleTCPSocket : public QAbstractSocket
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SimpleTCPSocket(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    void setHostInfo(const QString &hostName, quint16 port, QIODevice::OpenMode openMode = QIODevice::ReadWrite, QAbstractSocket::NetworkLayerProtocol protocol = QAbstractSocket::AnyIPProtocol);
    void setProxyInfo(QNetworkProxy::ProxyType proxyType, QString proxyHostName, quint16 proxyPort, QString username, QString password);
    void connectSimpleSocketToHost();
private:
    QNetworkProxy simpleSocketProxy;
    QString proxyUser, proxyPassword;
    QString hostName;
    int hostPort;
    QAbstractSocket::NetworkLayerProtocol protocol;
    QIODevice::OpenMode openMode;
    bool isHostSet, isConnectionOK, isProxySet;
private slots:
    void onHostFound(); // # slot 1
    void onSocketConnected(); // # slot 2
    void onSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error); // # slot 3
    void onUpdateSocketState(QAbstractSocket::SocketState state); // # slot 4
    void onProxyAuthRequired(const QNetworkProxy &simpleSocketProxy, QAuthenticator *authenticator); // # slot 5
    void onSocketAboutToClose(); // # slot 6
    void onSocketClose(); // # slot 7
signals:
    void remoteHostName(QString remoteHostName); // emmited whenever the host is found
    void attemptToConnectFinished(QString resultMessage); // emitted when the method connect is executed, attempt to connect to host
    void errorMessage(QString errorMessage); // emitted whenever an error occurs
    void socketStateMessage(QString socketState); // emitted whenever the socket state is changed
    void connectionInfo(QString connectionInformation); // emmited whenever the
};
```

Here is the implementation of my class:

```
#include "simpletcpsocket.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTime>

SimpleTCPSocket::SimpleTCPSocket(QObject *parent)
    :QAbstractSocket(QAbstractSocket::TcpSocket, parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(hostFound()), this, SLOT(onHostFound()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(onSocketConnected()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(onSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)), this, SLOT(onUpdateSocketState(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(proxyAuthenticationRequired(const QNetworkProxy &, QAuthenticator *)), this, SLOT(onProxyAuthRequired(const QNetworkProxy &, QAuthenticator *)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(aboutToClose()), this, SLOT(onSocketAboutToClose()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onSocketClose()));
    isHostSet = false;
    isConnectionOK = false;
    isProxySet = false;
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::connectSimpleSocketToHost()
{
    if (isProxySet)
    {
        this->setProxy(simpleSocketProxy);
    }
    else
    {
        this->setProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy);
    }
    if (isHostSet)
    {
        QTime t;
        t.start();
        static_cast<QAbstractSocket*>(this)->connectToHost(hostName, hostPort, openMode, protocol);
        emit attemptToConnectFinished("Attempt to connect to host ended. Time elapsed: " + QString::number(t.elapsed()) + " ms");
    }
    else
    {
        emit errorMessage("Host has not been set. You must set host name, port, open mode, and IP protocol first.");
    }
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::onHostFound()
{
    emit remoteHostName("Remote host name: " + static_cast<QAbstractSocket*>(this)->peerName());
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::onSocketConnected()
{
    isConnectionOK = true;
    QString connectionInfoString;
    connectionInfoString = "Peer address: " + this->peerAddress().toString();
    connectionInfoString += "; Peer port: " + QString::number(this->peerPort());
    connectionInfoString += "; Local address: " + this->localAddress().toString();
    connectionInfoString += "; Local port: " + QString::number(this->localPort());
    connectionInfoString += ";";
    emit connectionInfo(connectionInfoString);
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::onSocketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)
{
    switch(error)
    {
        case QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The connection was refused by the peer (or timed out).");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The remote host closed the connection. Note that the client socket (i.e., this socket) will be closed after the remote close notification has been sent.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::HostNotFoundError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The host address was not found.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::SocketAccessError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The socket operation failed because the application lacked the required privileges.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::SocketResourceError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The local system ran out of resources (e.g., too many sockets).");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::SocketTimeoutError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The socket operation timed out.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::DatagramTooLargeError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The datagram was larger than the operating system's limit (which can be as low as 8192 bytes).");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::NetworkError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("An error occurred with the network (e.g., the network cable was accidentally plugged out).");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::AddressInUseError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The address specified to QAbstractSocket::bind() is already in use and was set to be exclusive.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::SocketAddressNotAvailableError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The address specified to QAbstractSocket::bind() does not belong to the host.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::UnsupportedSocketOperationError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The requested socket operation is not supported by the local operating system (e.g., lack of IPv6 support).");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ProxyAuthenticationRequiredError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The socket is using a proxy, and the proxy requires authentication.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::SslHandshakeFailedError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The SSL/TLS handshake failed, so the connection was closed (only used in QSslSocket)");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::UnfinishedSocketOperationError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("Used by QAbstractSocketEngine only, The last operation attempted has not finished yet (still in progress in the background).");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ProxyConnectionRefusedError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("Could not contact the proxy server because the connection to that server was denied");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ProxyConnectionClosedError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The connection to the proxy server was closed unexpectedly (before the connection to the final peer was established)");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ProxyConnectionTimeoutError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The connection to the proxy server timed out or the proxy server stopped responding in the authentication phase.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ProxyNotFoundError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The proxy address set with setProxy() (or the application proxy) was not found.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ProxyProtocolError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The connection negotiation with the proxy server failed, because the response from the proxy server could not be understood.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::OperationError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("An operation was attempted while the socket was in a state that did not permit it.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::SslInternalError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("The SSL library being used reported an internal error. This is probably the result of a bad installation or misconfiguration of the library.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::SslInvalidUserDataError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("Invalid data (certificate, key, cypher, etc.) was provided and its use resulted in an error in the SSL library.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::TemporaryError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("A temporary error occurred (e.g., operation would block and socket is non-blocking).");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError:
        {
            emit errorMessage("An unknown socket error occurred.");
            break;
        }
    }
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::onUpdateSocketState(QAbstractSocket::SocketState state)
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState:
        {
            isConnectionOK = false;
            emit socketStateMessage("The socket is not connected.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState:
        {
            emit socketStateMessage("The socket is performing a host name lookup.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState:
        {
            emit socketStateMessage("The socket has started establishing a connection.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState:
        {
            isConnectionOK = true;
            emit socketStateMessage("A connection is established.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::BoundState:
        {
            emit socketStateMessage("The socket is bound to an address and port.");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ClosingState:
        {
            emit socketStateMessage("The socket is about to close (data may still be waiting to be written).");
            break;
        }
        case QAbstractSocket::ListeningState:
        {
            emit socketStateMessage("For internal use only.");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            emit socketStateMessage("Unkown state.");
        }
    }
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::onProxyAuthRequired(const QNetworkProxy &proxy, QAuthenticator *authenticator)
{
    qDebug() << "Proxy authentication required.";
    this->setProxy(proxy);
    this->proxy().setUser(proxyUser);
    this->proxy().setPassword(proxyPassword);
    authenticator->setUser(proxyUser);
    authenticator->setPassword(proxyPassword);
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::onSocketAboutToClose()
{
    qDebug() << "Connection about to close. Saving pending data to log (not implemented yet).";
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::onSocketClose()
{
    qDebug() << "Connection closed. Saving and closing log (not implemented yet).";
    isConnectionOK = false;
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::setHostInfo(const QString &hostName, quint16 port, QIODevice::OpenMode openMode, QAbstractSocket::NetworkLayerProtocol protocol)
{
    this->hostName = hostName;
    this->hostPort = port;
    this->openMode = openMode;
    this->protocol = protocol;
    isHostSet = true;
}

void SimpleTCPSocket::setProxyInfo(QNetworkProxy::ProxyType proxyType, QString proxyHostName, quint16 proxyPort, QString username, QString password)
{
    simpleSocketProxy.setType(proxyType);
    simpleSocketProxy.setHostName(proxyHostName);
    simpleSocketProxy.setPort(proxyPort);
    simpleSocketProxy.setUser(username);
    simpleSocketProxy.setPassword(password);
    isProxySet = true;
}
```

What is possibly wrong with my code?

Regards

Comment: @WindyFields I added the code for my class. It is a very simple implementation of QAbstracSocket.

Comment: if I were you, I would just replace your custom socket with QTcpSocket (in debugging purposes) and see if it works. Your explicitly say: on disconnect signal output Disconnected. So if it works, then you messed up with your SimpleSocket class, if it does not, than either your connection is not actually "disconnected" or there are some problems with reading from socket... Sorry, I don's see any other reasons of a such strange behavior. Also, you should probably try reading data from QDataStream [like in the example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html).

Comment: @WindyFields I replaced my custom socket with QTcpSocket and it worked fine.Probably, there is something wrong with my implementation.

Comment: @WindyFields thanks for your hint on how to read data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question at Qt Forum then I got this [answer](https://forum.qt.io/topic/82668/qabstractsocket-strange-behavior-when-connection-is-closed-from-server-side). raven-worx wrote: "nothing is wrong with your implementation. This is rather normal behavior unfortunately).". So, the problem is "solved".